# C Check all occurrences of a letter appear before another letter

Tags: c, find-occurrences, letter

So i have a string S consisting of N letters 'a' or 'b'.
This should return 1 if all occurrences of A are before all occurrences of b and return 0 otherwise.

B does not need to occur in S and A does not need to occur in S

For example

```
S='aabbb' returns 1 
S = 'ba' returns 0
S = 'aaa' returns 1
S= 'b' returns 1
```

So my approach was to use a for loop on the string and check if b occurs before a or not like so:

```
char newstr[10] = "aabbba"; //should return 0


int len = strlen(newstr);

for (int i = 0; i < len+1; i++) {
    printf("%c", newstr[i]);
    if (newstr[i] < 'b') {
        printf("1");
    }
    else {
        printf("0");
    }

}
```

Output is `a1a1b0b0b0a1 1` So..it is partially detecting if a is before b but not to its fully correct manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is simply detecting `a` without checking the relationship with `b`.

The condition "This should return 1 if all occurrences of A are before all occurrences of b and return 0 otherwise." can be said as "This should return **0** if **some** occurrences of A are **after some** occurrences of  b and return **1** otherwise.".

An example implementation of this is:

```
char newstr[10] = "aabbba";

int b_found = 0;
int result = 1;
for (int i = 0; newstr[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (newstr[i] == 'b') {
        b_found = 1;
    } else if(b_found && newstr[i] == 'a') {
        /* 'a' is found after 'b' */
        result = 0;
    }
}
printf("%d", result);
```

Comment: I see, but if we were to say have a method name with a paramater of a pointer `char *S`. Would I need to get the length of the char using `strlen(*S)` and then setting`char newstr[lengthOfChar] = *S` ? I'm confused on making a more general function.

Comment: No. `strlen(*S)` will lead to Segmentation fault and `char newstr[lengthOfChar] = *S` will lead to compile error. You can simply delete `char newstr[10] = "aabbba";`, replace all `newstr` to `S`, and use `S[i] != '\0'` to check if you dealt until the end of string.

Answer (score 7):

> i have a string S consisting of N letters 'a' or 'b'
>
> should return 1 if all occurrences of A are before all occurrences of b and return 0 otherwise.

So string is not allowed to have a sequence `ba` inside. So just:

```
if (strstr(newstr, "ba") == NULL) { printf("1\n"); } else { printf("0\n"); }
```

or just:

```
printf("%d\n", !strstr(newstr, "ba"));
```